# opacity with transition not running smooth in java script

Tags: javascript

I have a overlay div with opacity 0 and transition. Now when i use Javascript to set it's opacity to 1 it dosent fade in smoothly.?

```
 MoniqueDiv.style.display = 'block';
    MoniqueDiv.style.opacity = '1';
```

When clicked it simply display the overlay without any fade in style.
Please tell me how to fix this.
thanks.

Comment: if you show some HTML and CSS, we'd be able to point out where you've gone wrong

Comment: html and css would be required. check console also for any error. Ideally it should work fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epOeoN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED::

As you are moving the element from `display: none` to `display: block` you can make use of an entry animation possibly. Consider the following snippet. I've also added a button to fade out. You can make use of the `animationend` event when this is clicked to set `display:none` when the animation for fading out is complete.

```js
(function(){
  var fadeIn  = document.querySelector('.fade__in'),
      fadeOut = document.querySelector('.fade__out'),
      div     = document.querySelector('div');
  fadeIn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    div.className     = 'fading-in';
    div.style.display = 'block';
  });
  fadeOut.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var hideEl = function() {
      div.style.display = 'none';
      div.removeEventListener('animationend', hideEl);
    };
    div.addEventListener('animationend', hideEl);
    div.className = ' fading-out';
  });
  

}());
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
.fading-in {
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
.fading-out {
  animation: fadeOut 1s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
 from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
 from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<button class="fade__in">Fade in</button>
<button class="fade__out">Fade out</button>
```

If you run the snippet and click the button you'll see the div fade in. The fade is created by using an animation which is also used to fade the div back out. Ideally, and I think you can do it, is to use `animation-direction: reverse;` to use the same animation for in and out.

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: @Jh i am also doing a z-index:3333 to div... after that i am chaning opacity.,

Comment: and also displyaing it to block from none.. is that the problem?

Comment: Thanks Man. And what about if i want to fade out..Possibly a Reverse..I mean fadding on another button click.. thanks

Comment: I've added that for you now too. Fading out is a little trickier because you don't want to set `display: none` until you know the animation is complete.

Comment: I have other classes attached to the div to fade in. So i guess they will be washed away and fadein class sets in right?

Comment: ok i got it .. i have added fade In to the div using + operator. But i cannot get it to fade Out smoothly ..